# How to auto calculate a value in a textbox based on whether a checkbox is checked or not in ASP.NET MVC and C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a list view that lists all of the products that were ordered per order# (`OrderID`). I added a checkbox and a textbox on each product.

I'm trying to make it to where when the user opens up the form, when they go down the list of products from a particular order, if they check the checkbox it will auto calculate a value to insert into the textbox.

For example, there's two columns I want to add together to get the value for the textbox (`QtyOrdered` and `QtyAvailable`). So let's say for Order# 1: ProductA has a QtyAvailable of 4 and for that order they ordered 2.

What I want to happen is if the user checks the checkbox, then it would put the value of "QtyOrdered" + "QtyAvailable" (which would be 6) into the textbox. And if the user unchecks the checkbox, then that textbox value would go back to null or empty.

The reason I want to do this is because when we receive an order back, sometimes not all the products from that order come back so I want to be able to check which products we received back so it will add it back to inventory. I'm then going to use the textbox values to update the `QtyAvailable` column in another table when the form is submitted, but I just need help with solving the checkbox and textbox issue I'm having.

I am struggling to get it working properly. I got it working for just the first product, but if I click on any additional checkboxes, nothing happens. Also, I can't get it to change back to null or empty when I uncheck the checkbox. Any help would be great, I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and C# and would really appreciate any advice on what I'm doing wrong.

So far here is my view page:

```
   <table class="table">
   <tr>
       <th>
           Order #
       </th>
       <th>
           Product Code
       </th>
       <th>
           Qty Ordered
       </th>
       <th>
           Qty Available
       </th>
       <th>
           Qty Returned
       </th>
       <th>
           Return?
       </th>
       <th>
           New Qty Available
       </th>
   </tr>

   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       <tr>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.OrderID)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product_Code)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qty_Ordered)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qty_Available)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qty_Returned)
           </td>
           <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="return" onclick="newQuantity(this)">
           </td>
           <td>
               <input class="ctl-number" type="number" name="newQty" id="nsq" />
           </td>
       </tr>    
       <script>
           function newQuantity() {
              var returned = [];

               $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {

                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        returned.push($(this).val());
                        var qty = @item.Qty_Ordered.Value + @item.Qty_Available.Value;
                        $('#nsq').val(qty);
                    }
               })
           }
       </script>
   }
 </table>
```

Comment: Why don't you just have a "returned" flag bound to the checkbox and process it when the form is submitted? Though, that assumes all items of the same type are returned instead of say, two out of four.

Comment: I would like to point out that your inventory logic is flawed. If you take in returned items the quantity on hand probably won't be the same as when the order you are working on was processed. All you should care about is quantity returned is added to whatever the current on hand count is.

Comment: include the itemID in each checkbox and newQty input. That way you can update the correct items. Right now you're using the same id for each newQTY. (a big no-no... all IDs in the DOM should be unique...)  This this.id in your each function.

Comment: @pcalkins can you explain to me how to do that? I'm new to this so I'm still learning the ins and outs. What itemID should I add to the checkbox and textbox? They are both unbound to my database table, I just want to use them to get values to pass to the database table. I've tried adding item.OrderID to them but it didn't work, it put the value of the first product in all the textboxes. I think where I lack the most knowledge is in the function writing. Where would I put this.id in the each statement? thanks again!

Comment: @Crowcoder the QtyAvailable is the same thing as QtyOnHand. I probably didnt explain it that great, but those are the same thing. I have a QtyOnHold field when an order gets shipped out, it deducts from QtyAvailable and places the amount ordered in the OnHold field. When returned, the QtyOrdered amount will deduct from the OnHold amount and will get added back to the QtyAvailable. Hope that makes more sense. I just want it to be easier to return products from an order without having to manually change each product amount. I think the checkbox makes it easier and faster if I can get it working.

Comment: @KipM. Regardless, why don't you just add a boolean to the viewmodel and do the calculation on submit? It would be easier to do server side and you wouldn't have to worry about client side manipulation issues.

Comment: @Crowcoder yeah maybe I need to go that route. I thought I could the same thing with them unbound, but realizing it's probably more trouble than its worth. Do I have to add it to the database table and update the viewmodel or can I simply just add it in the viewmodel unmapped?

Comment: You can stuff anything you want in the ViewModel for use in the processing logic. You don't need to back it up all the way to the database.

Comment: @Crowcoder thank you, that's good to know! I'm going to try that out and see if it fixes my problem.

Comment: I'm still stuck on getting the page function to work before I submit the form. I would like to make it where when you check each checkbox, if it is checked it will insert the sum of QtyOrdered + QtyAvailable into the textbox. I'd like the user to see what it is adding back before submitting. Any suggestions on a jquery function or any function to try? I can't seem to get it to do the value for all the records instead of just the first record and if I unclick it, then the value still stays in the textbox and doesn't go back to null.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm still trying to get this to work on submit. Based on my view above, do you have any suggestions on the best way to loop through those records in my controller to only edit the records with a checkbox that is checked when I hit submit? What I've tried keeps saying there's no object set to reference. I added the checkbox to my model, its called "Return". I'm having a hard time finding anything online that works for this. They are all for new records or single records, and not for a continuous list editing of only the ones checked.